# Betiteln eines Antrags um einen Termin vorzuziehen

Tags: nominalization

Ich will einen Brief schreiben um einen Termin vorzuziehen (also auf einen früheren Termin verschieben). Mit welchem Wort kann ich den Antrag  "Terminänderung" oder "Terminverlegung" oder "Termin vorziehen" betiteln?

Comment: "Terminverschiebung" würde für mich als Muttersprachler auch ok klingen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are pretty close with your suggestions.

A **Terminverlegung** refers to all kinds of re-scheduling, both forward and back.

If you want to explicitly fix an earlier time, it's a **Terminvorverlegung**. The beloved German concept of compound nons in full swing ;-)

Now while one would perhaps expect a <del>**Terminnachverlegung**</del>, this word does not exist. Instead, a **Terminverschiebung** would typically indicate a later time.

Answer (score 1):

"Terminänderung" und "Terminverlegung" sind *beides* angemessene Ausdrücke. "Termin vorziehen" ist **keine Nominalisierung** und unterliegt somit anderen grammatikalischen Regeln. Außerdem klingt es auch schlichtweg nicht schön.